# XAML - VisualGroupState for HyperlinkButton (whats wrong?)

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, microsoft-metro, visualstatemanager

Trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong (first time playing with Visual States).  Can anyone point me to my problem?  The app is crashing ungracefully, nothing else to help beyond that.

Heres the xaml

```
<Style TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource HyperlinkTextBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation BeginTime="0" Duration="0.5" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="content"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                To="Red" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation BeginTime="0" Duration="0.5"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="content"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                To="White" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="content" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 3 places which you should correct:

1) The `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` tag must be situated inside the root control like a `Grid` and not in the `ControlTemplate`.

2) The `ContentPresenter` class doesn't have the `Foreground` property. But this property exists in the `ContentControl` class. After you replace this control, add explicit bindings for the properties `Content` and `Foreground`.

3) The value of the `Duration` property should be in seconds. Although you can use the expression `Duration="1"` which means 1 day, the value `0.5` crashes the application. Half of a second looks like `0:0:0.5`.

Here is the fixed style:

```
    <Style TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource HyperlinkTextBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="content"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            To="Red" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="content"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            To="White" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="content" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty sure I've put it inside the grid, maybe just copied stuff I was trying various times.

Comment: @Dave There are 2 another causes of the applciation crash. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks!  Still having issues, but crashing stopped.  I'll be able to work the rest out.